# How create new cell array in each loop in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

please help I want to create a new array in each loop iteration without deleting the array in the previous iteration.
if s(i)==1 i want it to create an array else i want it to create another array

```
ff=0;
 for j=1:2
     for i=1:6
         if(s(i)==j)


             ff=ff+1;
         end
     end

     for n=1:ff
         A = zeros(1,ff);
     end
 end
```

Comment: explain clearly with an example or give code what you done perviously..

Comment: i make edits to the post

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ff= zeros(2); % assign size of ff array as per your code array size is 2
for j=1:2
    ff(j)=0;
    for i=1:6
        if(s(i)==j)
            ff(j)=ff(j)+1;
        end
    end
    for n=1:ff(j)
          A{n}  = zeros(1,ff(j));
    end
end
```

may be it will use for you . Just create a variable ff with zeros(2). then use that variable like  above. So what happen , in single array your going to save multiple array value. Means whenever the loop of j is changing that time one more length is added in ff array.